# TypeError: expected bytes, str found in custom python function

Tags: python, function, encoding, error-handling, bioinformatics

I am using a new bioinformatics tool called Giggle and I have installed the python wrapper on my system.
Even though the scenario is quite specific, I think the problem is quite general.
This function:

```
index = Giggle.create("index", "HMEC_hg19_BroadHMM_ALL.bed")
```

should create an index based on several (or in this case one) .bed file.
The bed files look like this:

```
chr1    10000   10600   15_Repetitive/CNV   0   .   10000   10600   245,245,245
chr1    10600   11137   13_Heterochrom/lo   0   .   10600   11137   245,245,245
chr1    11137   11737   8_Insulator 0   .   11137   11737   10,190,254
chr1    11737   11937   11_Weak_Txn 0   .   11737   11937   153,255,102
chr1    11937   12137   7_Weak_Enhancer 0   .   11937   12137   255,252,4
chr1    12137   14537   11_Weak_Txn 0   .   12137   14537   153,255,102
chr1    14537   20337   10_Txn_Elongation   0   .   14537   20337   0,176,80
```

It is basically a large tab delimited file containing genomic intervals and their corresponding chromosome. When running the above command I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "giggle/giggle.pyx", line 25, in giggle.giggle.Giggle.create
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```

I have no clue why this is happening and I have tried converting the files to other types of encoding but nothing worked. The code snippet to which the error refers is as follows:

```
def create(self, char *path, char *glob):
    giggle_bulk_insert(to_bytes(glob), to_bytes(path), 1)
    return Giggle(path)
```

I am using Python 3.6 on a Linux subsystem for windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in python 3 strings are represented as unicode strings, not byte strings as it was the case in python 2. When you install giggle and run your code using python 2 everything works fine. But you can do:

```
index = Giggle.create("index".encode('utf-8'), "HMEC_hg19_BroadHMM_ALL.bed".encode('utf-8'))
```

or alternatively

```
index = Giggle.create(b"index", b"HMEC_hg19_BroadHMM_ALL.bed")
```

to have explicit byte strings. It worked for me, up to the point that giggle complains about the `.bed` file being incorrectly formatted (I probably messed up the format when copying)

**Update:**
There is another issue that comes up when calling it like described above:

> File type not supported 'HMEC_hg19_BroadHMM_ALL.bed'

Which is caused by the underlying lib `giggle` only accepting `.bed.gz` files, which can be seen in `python-giggle/lib/giggle/src/file_read.c`:

```
if ( (strlen(i->file_name) > 7) &&
    strcmp(".bed.gz", file_name + strlen(i->file_name) - 7) == 0) {
    i->type = BED;
}
```

So I am assuming that the Readme at the [python-giggle](https://github.com/brentp/python-giggle) site is not correct in claiming that you can call it with `.bed` files.

I tested it with one of the files provided in `python-giggle\lib\giggle\test\data` and it ran without an error

Comment: I am both suprised and amazed you got it working so quickly. When I do the same in a python2.7 env I get the following error: `File type not supported 'GM12878_hg19_BroadHMM_ALL.bed'.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. When I try either the .encode method or the b method in python3.6 I get the same error and when running tests in a jupyter notebook, my kernel instantly dies running the create index function. Since you got it working so quickly, could je help me on my way?

Comment: I got the same error but assumed it was due to me messing up the format (I have no idea what it is supposed to look like). But I found the solution I think, which is quite odd thoug

Comment: @MatthijsvanKesteren I have tried updating according to my findings

Comment: You have a very sharp eye. However, I am still not managing to run it on the test data without errors: `In [1]: from giggle import Giggle

In [2]: index = Giggle.create(b"new_index", b"1k.sort.bed.gz")
python: offset_index_store: Could not truncate.: Invalid argument` Which file did you exactly use?

Comment: You mean your own data or some from `python-giggle\lib\giggle\test\data`? What error are you getting?

Comment: I used the `1k.sort.bed.gz` from `python-giggle\lib\giggle\test\data` for creating the index. I am getting this error: `python: offset_index_store: Could not truncate.: Invalid argument`. I feel like we are slowly getting somewhere, although the road is slow and painful.

Comment: You get this error while creating the index or in some step after?

Comment: While creating the index, in both python2 and 3

Comment: I foun the error in the `offset_index.c` file at line 170 but I know basically nothing about C code to understand any of why the error is occuring

Comment: That's odd, I am not getting this error. You are just doing something like `python -c "from giggle import Giggle; index = Giggle.create('index'.encode('utf-8'), 'python-giggle/lib/giggle/test/data/1k.sort.bed.gz'.encode('utf-8'));"`?

Comment: I created a small `test.py` script like: `from giggle import Giggle
index = Giggle.create("index".encode("utf-8"), "1k.sort.bed.gz".encode("utf-8"))` and just run it using `python test.py`. I am quite lost now

Comment: Actually the same one, so I am unfortunately as lost as you are on this new bug

Answer (score 4):

The `create()` method expects byte strings:

```
create(self, char *path, char *glob):
```

Cython can only accept `bytes` objects in Python 3, `str` in Python 2, to convert to a `char` array automatically.

Either pass in `bytes` objects when you call the method (encoding your `str` objects first), or alter that method signature to accept `str` unicode strings. See [*Accepting strings from Python code*](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#accepting-strings-from-python-code) in the Cython tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Encoding your string in `utf-8` will solve your problem:

```
yourstr.encode('utf-8')
```