# Failure to write values to db using Azure function

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to using an Azure function to write data into an Azure SQL server.
I 've built three pipelines successfully but failed in this one.

I am trying to write a line to the database using:

```
cursor.execute("insert into beamSetupResults values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5], val[6], val[7], val[8], val[9], val[10], val[11])
```

And the values are (And I print these values during decoding the response so they are guruanteed to be string):

```
['800112', '', '2016-08-08T15:11:05Z', 'pass', 'Al-13kV-3', 13, 80000, 132.0092315673828, 79936.953125, '', False, True]
```

I got errors as follows:

```
[Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.TimeTrigger_BeamSetup. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: TypeError: expected bytes, str found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Repos\azure-python-siteextensions\source_packages\python.3.5.2\tools\Lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set 
ith an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: decoding with 'utf-16le' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_decode> returned a result with an error set)
```

Moreover, I am pretty these values matches the table of my database.
Before I got this error, it worked for several days.
I've tested these code locally and all of them works fine.

I am using pyodbc package and the driver is 13.

Any thoughts? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766390/typeerror-expected-bytes-str-found-in-custom-python-function as per this,*python 3 strings are represented as unicode strings, not byte strings as it was the case in python 2*

Comment: @Jayendran Sorry, I don't get this. The whole function is developed under py 3.5, why there will an error associated with py2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just upgrade your pyodbc package version and everything will be fine.